# Wordpress - Advanced Custom Fields gallery

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF plugin and i create a flexible content to show title, content and gallery but i can't get the images.

My code is this:

```
<div id="services-pages">
  <?php
    if( have_rows('serviços') ):
      while ( have_rows('serviços') ) : the_row();
      ?>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="title">
                    <hr>
                    <span><?php echo the_sub_field('title');?></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="info">
                    <p><?php echo the_sub_field('content');?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="row images">
                  <?php
                    $images = the_sub_field('images');
                    var_dump($images);

                  ?>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="slider-service-element">
                      <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                        <div>
                          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
                        </div>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="slider-service-main">
                      <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                        <div>
                          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
                        </div>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    else :
    ?>
    <div>
      <span>no records</span>
    </div>
    <?php
    endif;
  ?>
</div>
```

My ACF field:
[image: My ACF field]

I already try to get gallery with `get_field()` and `the_sub_field()`.
How can i solve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$images = get_sub_field('images');

if( $images ):
    foreach( $images as $image ):
        ?><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" /><?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

There's a post on acf forum about it

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/gallery-field-within-a-repeater-field/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( have_rows('glp_images') ):
// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('glp_images') ) : the_row();
                    
    $images = get_sub_field('glp_img');
    if( $images ): ?>
                    
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif;?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add also explanation on what this code is doing and how it will solve the issue?